# Technology choice, database

Tags: database, linux

I'm thinking about developing a database application with a web interface. basically I'll be using javascritp, ajax, php and xhtml. I was thinking on using the centos OS with "lamp". 
The database might get a little extensive...do you guys have any advice on what technologies (besides the one refereed) that I should look into?

Note: Must be free :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have never understood the open source's fascination with MySQL.  PostgreSQL is a way better database in just about every possible way.

Comment: I think PostgresSQL is a little harder to use, but in general its behaviour is less surprising (i.e. more consistent and less idiosynchratic). For that reason I would also consider it for a genuinely new project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing in selecting your DBMS is the nature of your application. Whats the purpose of your application.

If you goes in enterprise level you should select the proper DBMS for that support enterprise features.

If you just need to play around to learn the Database and coding  just try LAMP or XAMPP :)